# How can i read a text file key value and assign the values to strings vars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a text file in a new class using `StreamWriter` and `WriteLine`.
Each line i built it like this:

```
w.WriteLine("key2" + "=" + value2);
w.WriteLine("key1" + "=" + value1);
```

Then in form1 Load event:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
```

Now in lines i have in index 0 "key2 = value2" and in index 1 "key1 = value1"
Now i want to assign the lines each value to another string for example:

string value1 to be assigned with value1 of key1
and string value2 to be assigned with value2 of key2

Sometimes the order of the lines can be changed the first line in the text file can be value2 and key2 or value1 and key1 but in all cases i want that the string value1 to be assigned with value1 of key1 and string value2 to be assigned with value2 of key2

This time i built the text file manualy without keyvaluepair or something like that but when reading it back i want to read the left meaning as key and right after the = as value.

But if i'm doing:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Authentication.AuthenticationFileName);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{

}
```

How do i know always to assign to the strings in the order i want no matter the order the lines are written in the text file?

I wonder how it could be working if i build the text file like key and value: `key = value`

Comment: do you mean with *Dictionary*?  if so, you can read line by line and split the key and the value using split method by '='

Comment: You can create a Dictionary to store the Key and Value pair. Now read the properties through Dictionary. For ex `public string Key1 { get return _dict["Key1"]; } }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build a dictionary of values, keyed by name, to make it easier to access them:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Authentication.AuthenticationFileName);

// Get the position of the = sign within each line
var pairs = lines.Select(l => new { Line = l, Pos = l.IndexOf("=") });

// Build a dictionary of key/value pairs by splitting the string at the = sign
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Line.Substring(0, p.Pos), p => p.Line.Substring(p.Pos + 1));

// Now you can retrieve values by key:
var value1 = dictionary["key1"];
```

Comment: Great use of dictionary. I just added Trim at the end of substrings :)p.Line.Substring(0, p.Pos).Trim() to avoid whitespaces

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way of building the dictionary using the `Split` method and not indexing characters in a string:

```
//Load lines from file

var dict = lines.Select(line => line.Split('=')).ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);

var val1 = dict["key1"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Split` method to get right side values from `string`

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Authentication.AuthenticationFileName);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
  string val = lines[i].Split('=')[1].Trim();
}
```